# I have the iso image but wubi again downloading the whole data?

Tags: wubi, 13.10, kubuntu, bittorrent

I downloaded the Kubuntu 13.10 via torrent. But when I extracted the data and attempted to install Kubuntu while in Windows, the Wubi connects to the internet and downloads the whole ISO data again, so I cancelled the installation. What to do?

Comment: wubi.exe doesn't work in 13.10. It was discontinued in 13.04.

Comment: Wubi doesn't work, but theoretically you would place the 13.10 `wubi.exe` in the same folder as the ISO (don't extract it) and then it wouldn't not work as you haven't found that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**What happened:** The ISO you downloaded was meant to be burned to a disk or configured to a USB to install Kubuntu in that manner. However, if you choose to install it while you're on the Windows OS Wubi will download the required files again.

**What you can do:**

1. If you would like to install it alongside Windows OS, continue by starting the Wubi installer again, let it take awhile to download, and follow the reboot instructions once its finished.
2. Make a Linux USB creator, I suggest using [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Hoped that helped.

Comment: Wubi is discontinued; you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @alex i have a similar problem with ubuntu 14.04 that i have just downloaded. I'm trying a wubi install using Universal USB Installer but it's downloading whole data again. any solution?\