# Installing lubuntu 14.04 alternate with wubi

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lubuntu, wubi

I have an old laptop with 256 MB RAM with windows XP. It doesn't have a working cd/dvd rom and the BIOS does not allow to boot from usb. Is there a way to install lubuntu 14.04(alternate version) through wubi on this system.? Or any method that might work even if I don't need dual-boot?

Comment: WUBI is no longer supported. You can read more about this here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download it to your machine, and run from windows as `D:\wubi.exe`
EDIT:
You can't install Wubi from an alternate ISO. For 12.04.2, if you want to install from a 32bit desktop ISO, you can save it in the same folder as wubi.exe before running (both available from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04
This wubi.exe can also install standalone (no ISO).

To install from the 64bit desktop ISO (not alternate), there is a bug which has been patched, but not released so you'll need to use the wubi.exe from here: http://people.canonical.com/~evand/w...273-signed.exe  Save that in the same folder as the desktop-amd64 ISO before running. [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139162)

Comment: I tried that but it does not work for the alternate iso. It starts to download lubuntu 14.04. I have placed the alternate iso in the same folder as wubi.

Comment: yes, it downloads a file. You need to wait until it is finished. Here are discussions [link1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369306/i-have-the-iso-image-but-wubi-again-downloading-the-whole-data), [link2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294363/wubi-is-downloading-file-but-i-have-full-iso)

Comment: will this download the alternate iso? the one for PC's with less than 512 MB RAM?

Comment: sorry, I edited answer, look at EDIT portion.

Comment: For completeness sake, I'd like to point out that WUBI is no longer supported. You can read more about this here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766 Another good run-down is located here: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

Some computers such as my old Dell 1000 recognize a flash drive as another hard drive so with a flash drive inserted check the BIOS and see if it is listed under hard drives.  If it is you may be able to boot from a flash drive just move it to the top of the list under hard drives.
Now of course you will have to prepare the flash drive to make it bootable.
You may be able to install Lubuntu with only 256 Mbs of Ram, but you might not be able to do a lot with it.  My Dell had 256 Mbs of RAM so I got another 256 Mb chip and it runs fine.